# How to enable express/fastify to support absolute paths import?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, next.js, fastify

In Next.js, I used to use `import UserModel from "models/UserModel"` to import ESM modules without any prefix and extension such as `.js`, just [refer to the document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) to set the relative path in `jsconfig.json`.

But express/fastify don't support these two features:

- import from the project root directory instead of `../../models/UserModel`
- no extension, especially if `"type": "module"` is set in `package.json`

I guess it might have something to do with babel? But I can't get started.
What should I do to be like next.js?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the babel part. Rewriting or resolving the relative imports is a job of either a runtime (Node.js) or a module bundler (Webpack, parcel, etc). Express or Fastify do not come with CLI or a built-in bundler.

The next.js is not just a library but also provides a CLI which internally makes use of Webpack to bundle multiples files into a one or more larger files.

Also, just using Babel is not enough. It is a compiler (transpiler to be specific) but not a module bundler.

This is what is happening in your case. When Babel encounters `import UserModel from "models/UserModel"`, it leaves the import statement untouched and compiles rest of the code. At max, it may convert the ES import to CJS `require` call like `const UserModel = require('models/UserModel');` if you have configured the Babel like that. So, when you try to execute this code and when `node.js` runtime looks at your code, it tries to find the `UserModel` in the files:

- `<ROOT>/node_modules/models/UserModel.js` or
- `<ROOT>/node_modules/models/UserModel/index.js`

So, you would need to use something like Webpack to achieve this. You would have to use custom [resolve configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) like this:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // ... other configuration
  target: "node",
  resolve: {
    alias: {
     "models/UserModel": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/models/UserModel'),
    },
  },
};
```

Also, if you are bundling the code for Node.js then set the [target](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) to `node`.